# How much does it cost to issue my own custom token on Stellar?

Tags: assets

Can anyone tell me the breakdown of costs incurred should I decide to issue my custom token on Stellar?

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about the network costs, they are almost negligible.

- 1 XLM + change, for the issuing account
- 1.5 XLM + change, for the distribution account

Fees are 1 XLM per 100,000 operations, and you need a handful, or two, of those.

Answer (score 1):

There are the base fees on stellar, which are almost nothing. You need to plan on having an issuing account, a distribution account and maybe a warm reserve account. With trustlines, etc. about 8-10 XLM goes a long way.

The real cost is all the rest. You will need a domain + stellar.toml hosted somewhere with https. So, you have to consider the hosting cost for that as well.

Comment: So basically I need a few XLMs for issuing my own tokens. The reason for me asking is that I have one so called "expert" in Stellar said that I need to pay USD50k for a whole Stellar block?(Whatever that means) so that I can use the network and also would not need to pay the 100 stroops transaction fee. Is this true?Im confused...

Comment: Sounds like someone wants to sell you your own network. Again, as both Jilles and I have mentioned, the actual on-chain costs of generating your asset is tiny, but of course there's supporting infrastructure and software that might be needed, depending on your requirements. If we're talking about your own network, with multiple validator nodes (+maintenance), custom wallet software, and an ICO and everything around it, 50k might be OK.